# How to get avast! on computer after getting the download?

Tags: software-installation

I downloaded avast! and have `avast4workstation_1.3.0-2_i386.deb` as the downloaded file. What do I do next to finish installation?

Answer (score 5):

## Graphical way

1. Double click the file. It should open in the **Ubuntu Software Centre**.
2. Click the '**Install**' button near the top right corner.
3. Type your account password if required.
4. Wait for it to be installed.
5. Run it from the Dash.

## Command-line way

Do the following (from [Goldentoa11's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350954/how-to-get-avast-on-computer-after-getting-the-download#comment449716_350956)):

1. Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).
2. Execute the following command (substituting the correct path to the file):

   ```
    dpkg -i "/path/to/file.deb"
   ```

For future reference, all files ending in `.deb` can be installed either way.

Note: As said in the comments, you'll need a serial number from the avast! website first.

Comment: Addition: In the case of Avast, you also have to register on their site to get a serial number.

Comment: Also, if you prefer the terminal, you can run `dpkg -i debname.deb`